# Properties of Characteristic Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, characteristic-subgroups

I am new to characteristic subgroups, and have a theorem without a proof I don't understand yet.  It says that if $A$ is characteristic in a group $G$ and $B$ is characteristic in $G$, then both $AB$ and $A\cap B$ are characteristic in $G$, i.e., characteristicity is closed under intersections and products.  The book says the proof is trivial so it skips it, but I guess I'm not understanding the concept enough yet to see why this would be true.

Could anyone give me a quick intuitive reason why this is true and show me why the proof is "trivial"?  I see online that people use this fact all the time, but can't seem to find any formal justification for it or proof of it.  Thanks in advance for humoring me with a beginner's question...I'm sure it's not too hard once I see it.

Comment: To verify that $A\cap B$ is characteristic simply use the definition: Let $\alpha$ be an automorphism of $G$ and $x\in A\cap B$. Is it clear that $\alpha(x)\in A\cap B$? This means precisely that $A\cap B$ is characteristic in $G$. For $AB$, you can use the fact that the elements of $AB$ have the form $x_1x_2\cdots x_n$ with $x_i\in A\cup B$.

Comment: This is simply "verify things satisfy the appropriate definitions", which you should really get used to.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro I'm not very clear about the product case. Could you give more hint please?

Comment: @Miranda It depends a little on your definition of "product". I'll use the following: $AB$ is the smallest subgroup of $G$ which contains $A$ and $B$. Let $\alpha$ be an automorphism of $G$. Then $\alpha(A)\subseteq A\subseteq AB$, so $A\subseteq\alpha^{-1}(AB)$. Similarly, $B\subseteq\alpha^{-1}(AB)$. Thus $\alpha^{-1}(AB)$ is a subgroup which contains both $A$ and $B$, so it contains $AB$. This means that $AB\subseteq\alpha^{-1}(AB)$, that is, $\alpha(AB)\subseteq AB$.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ si characteristic iff $\forall\psi\in\operatorname{Aut}(G),\,\psi(A)\subset A$.

For any map $\psi(A\cap B)\subset \psi(A)\cap\psi(B)$. In the case of characteristic subgroups we have for any automorphism

$$\psi(A\cap B)\subset \psi(A)\cap\psi(B)\subset A\cap B$$

And this proves the closedness under intersection

Do you feel like proving it for the product ?

Comment: I see where you're going with this and appreciate the answer...I think I'm getting stuck on a technicality because my book's definition is that phi(A) = A, not phi(A) is a subset of A.  Are the two equivalent?

Comment: To see that they are equivalent, note that $\psi^{-1}$ is also an automorphism of $G$.

Comment: Oooh, very good point there.  Thanks so much - the intersection case makes perfect sense now!  Still a tad fuzzy on the product case, but perhaps I just need to play with it a little more.